# Ubuntu 16.04 webcam no sound in applications

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, webcam, microphone

I have 16.04 fully updated. I have a creative webcam. The video works fine but there is no sound recording in Skype, Google Hangouts, Cheese etc. Hangouts will work if I change from default microphone in hangout settings to my webcam. In Ubuntu sound settings the webcam is the selected input device and the orange bars move when I speak, so I would have thought the webcam is the default but chrome thinks not. I think my "default" microphone is not the same one as shown in the sound settings. I notice also that the sound settings only offers me my webcam, not the internal microphone. Something is messed up. Any ideas?.